# How to graph quadratic forms and label points closest to and furthest from the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, curves

1. $x_1^2+4x_2^2+9x_3^2=1$
2. $x_1^2+4x_2^2-9x_3^2=1$
3. $-x_1^2-4x_2^2+9x_3^2=1$

---

I have to sketch these three surfaces and determine which are "bounded", which are "connected", and what the points closest to/furthest from $(0,0)$ are for each surface.

For each $q\,(\vec{x})=\lambda_1c_1^2+\lambda_2c_2^2+\lambda_3c_3^2$, it seems like I have to intuitively just know which of $\left\{c_1,c_2,c_3\right\}$ is closest to the origin and set that equal to zero to solve for the level curves (level sets?).

Is there a more explicit formula/algorithm for this within linear algebra (i.e. no Lagrange Multipliers or partial derivatives)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "knowing which is closest to the origin"

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem) will hopefully clarify what I mean. "For example, the maximum distance from the origin on the ellipse $c_1^2+9c_2^2=1$ occurs when $c_2=0$, so at the points $\pm1$. Similarly, the minimum distance is where $c_2=\pm\frac{1}{3}$"

Comment: The shape of the coefficients suggest rewriting your forms as $x_1^2 \pm (2 x_2)^2 \pm (3 x_3)^2$. Then they may become revolution surfaces, for example around the $x_3$-axis. Drawing the generatrix should give you an idea about the shape of the surface.

Comment: The short answer appears to be "find the coefficient that differs from the others and set $c_i=k$" after drawing a picture